# What is the reason of such error " XML or text declaration not at start of entity" when parsing xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, httpconnection

I have this `xml` result from calling the page `getRout.php`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"> 
  <Document> 
    <name>KML Samples</name> 
    <open>1</open> 
    <distance>20.831418618295</distance> 
    <description>To enable simple instructions add: 'instructions=1' as parameter to the URL</description> 
    <Folder> 
.
.
.
.
</kml>
```

I use this jquery script retrieve xml response :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getRout.php",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('coordinates').each(function(){
                            var t = $(this).text();
                            alert(t);

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

### edit

this is the content of `getRout.php` file ..

```
<?
require_once "RESTclient.class.php";
$url = "http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik";
header("Content-type:text/xml");
$result = RestClient::get($url,$inputs); 
echo($result->getResponse());
?>
```

Comment: usually this problem means the xml doesn't start with `<?xml?>`properly .check is there any white spaces before that

Comment: check again and really makesure

Comment: I have edited the question .. check getRout.php script

Comment: Are you using Firebug or similar? What does that tool tell you is the *exact* content of the XHR response? Have you tried accessing the `getRout.php` page directly with a browser? What does the view source say?

Comment: access the getRout.php directly .. gives me : XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://127.0.0.1/direction2/getRout.php
Line Number 2, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^

Comment: `Line Number 2, Column 1` this explain the error, it should always start at line number 1. Check your script and RESTclient.class.php to check for the line-break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `getRout.php`. Is there whitespace after the closing `?>` tag?  You can try removing the closing tag altogether to ensure that no extra whitespace is being added to your response.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89553/closing-tag-on-php-files